# Redirect the whole blog to SSL but not the RSS feed (under Nginx)

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have an Nginx installation and sadly, I'm seeing that a few posts aren't appearing on Feedburner because some sort of problem between Feedburner and SSL (I moved my blog to SSL recently).

So, I thought a solution might be to redirect the whole blog to SSL, but, in Nginx, adding a rule so the `/feed` can be crawlable by Feedburner over plain HTTP. I've done this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain www.domain.com;

    root /home/mydomain/public_html;

    location /feed {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/mydomain/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
    }

    location / {
            return 301 https://www.mydomain.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Sadly, it's not working. I keep receiving a 404 from the first `location` directive. There's another problem, because PHP has to be called to execute itself on that location, `/feed` so that might be the source of the problem.

Comment: isn't feedburner a dead product?